# Animation between activities in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I’m doing a mobile app and I want to do some animation between activities when a button is pressed. Currently my code looks like this and theoretically it should work since it works for everyone else … help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!!

```
val intent = Intent(this,Login::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
this@LoginRegister.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animate_card_enter , R.anim.animate_card_exit)
```

I tried something related with ActivityOptions but it didn’t work aswell…